# c++ with custom 3D graphics library - Writing a while loop with the or operator between conditions

Tags: c++

Im trying to write a looping block of code that codes that asks the following following within c++

`while object A, or B or C or D == X, Y, Z (coords)`

`if A meets conditions, move object A East.`

`If B meets conditions, move object B East.`

and so on,

I've pre-established each object coords as a string, so I just need to compare them against a control, Currently, I just have a loop that happens that doesn't recognise ***which object*** is triggering it.

The code to read coords and move the object is within a specific library, My tutor suggests using an array and a while loop to achieve this but I'm not sure how to do it even after spending several hours researching it.

I come from a background of unity and unreal engine so something simple like this goes over my head because I want to just use a conditional on the point, rather than react to each of the objects.

I'm very fresh to c# so please try to keep solutions simple thankyou!

EDIT: This is the code I am using at the moment

````
//Load strings at the start of the game
```string bblocal = (ballblue->GetLocalX, ballblue->GetLocalY, ballblue->GetLocalZ);
        string bilocal = (ballindigo->GetLocalX,ballbindigo->GetLocalY, ballindigo->GetLocalZ);
        string bvlocal = (ballviolet->GetLocalX,ballviolet->GetLocalY, ballviolet->GetLocalZ);
        string bflocal = (ballfawn->GetLocalX,ballfawn->GetLocalY, ballfawn->GetLocalZ);

        string bb = bblocal;
        string bi = bilocal;
        string bv = bvlocal;
        string bf = bflocal;```

  //For each tick, check the following
```while (bb || bi || bv || vf == (-50, 10, 50)
        {
            //Turn blue and move it to next point
if blue
{
ballblue->MoveX (0);
ballblue->MoveZ (100);
ballblue->RotateX (-50);
ballblue->RotateZ (50);
}
            //Turn Indigo and move it to next point
            //Turn Violet and move it to next point
            //Turn Fawn and move it to next point

        }
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show your real code. Check how to create a [repro].

Comment: Store objects that need to be check in an array. For each elemnt of this array do the check, if it's good make the move on the current object leave the loop . But do all object need to be moved if they all validate the condition or the first one? does the order matter?

Comment: So we have 4 balls moving in a square, when each ball hits the corner of the square, it needs to turn and keep moving 90 degrees, and also change its rotation 90 degrees.
because its built on a custom library its not possible to recreate, Edit following with example of what I have tried so far.

Comment: I just check the update question. And I wonder is C# the right tag? Is that C#?

Comment: This is C++ with a 3D graphics Library.
Another class I take is learning C# so I was under the impression they were the same languagefor the last week, I only just found out today that this engine uses c++, Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help guys :D

Answer (score 1):

With a given class Point like:

```
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

You have a brunch of define point:

```
var A = new Point{X=1, Y=0, Z=0};
var B = new Point{X=0, Y=1, Z=0};
var C = new Point{X=0, Y=0, Z=1};
// Etc
```

And a refenrece point to compare them with. List all the point you have to check in an array.

```
var referencePoint = new Point{X=0, Y=0, Z=1};
var pointsToCheck = new []{A, B, C};
```

An for each element of this array do your validation. You can have access  to the point via the variable.

```
foreach(var p in pointsToCheck){

    // Would be nice If Point add IEquatable<Point> with Equals gethashcode
    if(    p.X == referencePoint.X
        && p.Y == referencePoint.Y
        && p.Z == referencePoint.Z
    )
    {
        //Do something!
        p.X ++;
        // Break; // if only the first must be moved.
    }
}
```

Query them directly with LinQ

```
pointsToCheck.Where( p => p.X == referencePoint.X
        && p.Y == referencePoint.Y
        && p.Z == referencePoint.Z) ;
```

If you have an array of "corner" you point position in it, you will need the IEquatable.

```
var currentCornerIndex = Array.IndexOf(cornersList, CurrentPoint);
//Will return the next corner: 
// if it's the last corner return the first
// if not a corner return the first.
var nextCornerIndex = (currentCornerIndex + 1) % cornersList.Length;
var nextCorner = cornersList[nextCornerIndex];
```